# Footer disappears when using the_content ( )

Tags: functions, hooks

I have an issue when using  [`the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) -- the footer of the page disappears and no errors are displayed.

When I change [`the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) to [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) and echo this results then it works fine.

What's the issue behind this scenario?

Comment: You have, in most probabilty, a styling issue like an open div or something. `get_the_content` works as it is unfiltered

Comment: enable DEBUG to see if you get warning or error messages; https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

An important difference from the_content() is that get_the_content() does not pass the content through the 'the_content'. This means that get_the_content() will not auto-embed videos or expand shortcodes, among other things.

If you find yourself annoyed with formatting of the content, more specifically the added p-tags that WordPress puts into the content that you didn’t. Just use
and you will remove those tags.

```
get_the_content();
```